# db2 Recursive with min and max records

Tags: db2, db2-400

We would need from this table :

```
drop table relations; 
create table relations (OLD_GID varchar(60), NEW_GID varchar(60)); 
insert into relations values('GID5','GID4'); 
insert into relations values('GID4','GID3'); 
insert into relations values('GID2','GID1'); 
insert into relations values('GID3','GID2'); 
insert into relations values('GID10','GID11'); 
insert into relations values('GID20','GID21'); 
insert into relations values('GID30','GID32'); 
insert into relations values('GID31','GID32'); 
insert into relations values('GID40','GID42'); 
insert into relations values('GID41','GID42'); insert into relations values('GID42','GID43');
```

End with a table like this

```
OLD_GID                                             NEW_GID           

------------------------------------------------------------
GID5                                                GID1  
GID4                                                GID1  
GID3                                                GID1 
GID2                                                GID1

GID40                                               GID43 
GID41                                               GID43 
GID42                                               GID43

GID10                                               GID11

GID20                                               GID21

GID30                                               GID32 
GID31                                               GID32
```

meaning
if I have :
Gid1  father is Gid2
Gid2  father is Gid3

then the output would be

Gid1 with father of all that is  Gid3
Gid2 with father of all that is  Gid3

I started to write this query But I'm stuck

```
WITH RPL (OLD_GID, NEW_GID) AS
     (  SELECT ROOT.OLD_GID, ROOT.NEW_GID
        FROM relations ROOT
        WHERE ROOT.OLD_GID in ( select OLD_GID from relations where OLD_GID  not in ( select NEW_GID from relations ))
      UNION ALL
        SELECT CHILD.OLD_GID, CHILD.NEW_GID
        FROM RPL PARENT, relations CHILD
        WHERE  PARENT.NEW_GID = CHILD.OLD_GID
     )
select --  row_number() over(order by 1) as genkeycol  , OLD_GID, NEW_GID
        OLD_GID, NEW_GID
from RPL
```

Thank You -

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH T (OLD_GID, NEW_GID) AS
(
  SELECT *
  FROM RELATIONS P
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM RELATIONS C WHERE C.OLD_GID = P.NEW_GID)
    UNION ALL
  SELECT R.OLD_GID, T.NEW_GID
  FROM RELATIONS R, T
  WHERE R.NEW_GID = T.OLD_GID
)
SELECT * 
FROM T
ORDER BY NEW_GID, OLD_GID
```

The result is:

| OLD_GID | NEW_GID |
| --- | --- |
| GID2 | GID1 |
| GID3 | GID1 |
| GID4 | GID1 |
| GID5 | GID1 |
| GID10 | GID11 |
| GID20 | GID21 |
| GID30 | GID32 |
| GID31 | GID32 |
| GID40 | GID43 |
| GID41 | GID43 |
| GID42 | GID43 |

Comment: Fantastic, thank you :)

Comment: Great! Please, mark the answer as accepted then.